# Do Transformers have operating systems?

Tags: transformers

Do the Transformers like Megatron, Optimus Prime and the like have operating systems? If so, can these extremely advanced Windows/Linux/MacOS etc. be hacked and reprogrammed as is possible with virtually any operating system?

Comment: “Windows/Linux/MacOS” indeed! It’s OS2/Warp all the way down.

Comment: In the comics continuity, Transformers can be stored on a floppy disk: (Just one 5.25" floppy disk!) http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Afterdeath!

Comment: According to movies, we invented silicon chips, operating systems by reverse engineering Transformers (especially Megatron)...

Comment: I would say even humans have operating systems, the software your brain runs in its hardware.

Answer (score 8):

This is addressed in Episode 1 ["The Reformatting"](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/The_Reformatting), Beast Machines, Season 1:

> Cheetor: Did I miss something? This is Cybertron, right? Our home
>   planet? I mean, why would our own kind shoot at us?
>
> Rattrap: Heheheh, have ya looked in the mirror lately? Our 'own kind'
>   don't recognize us in these lousy fur coats!
>
> Cheetor: Not a problem. We just need to get to a Regeneration Chamber
>   and debug this transforming glitch!
>
> Rattrap: Hellooo? We're in da MIDDLE OF NOWHERE HERE!
>
> Cheetor: (Feels pain in his servos; glitching continues) AAAGGGHHH!!
>
> Optimus Primal: It's worse than I thought... If we don't Transform out
>   of these Beast Modes soon, our **operating systems** will shut down...
>   permanently.
>
> -- Optimus Primal, Cheetor & Rattrap discuss about the transformation lock and Cybertron's major changes...

&

Episode 6 "Home Soil", Beast Machines, Season 2:

> Botanica: Megatron's attack shorted out my ship, along with my higher
>   reasoning protocols. My self-preservation circuits must have kicked
>   in.
>
> Optimus Primal: Which is why you were lashing out at us.
>
> Botanica: Fortunately, your reformatting automatically rebooted my
>   primary **operating system**.
>
> -- Botanica is exhibiting symptoms of Megatron's virus. Optimus Primal reformats her. She recovers consciousness.

Comment: Good find, though you have to wonder if the writers understood what they meant by "operating systems".

Comment: @Wikis Obviously they do; see my recent edit.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which continuity you're referring to, it's a touch unclear as it's often never explicitly stated either way.

However, we have seen Transformers reprogrammed or controlled remotely.

In [The Secret of Omega Supreme](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Secret_of_Omega_Supreme_%28episode%29), we learn that Megatron has reprogrammed the Constructicons to become Decepticons.

In Beast Machines, we eventually learn that Tankor, Jetstorm, and Thrust are reprogrammed/reformatted Maximals/Predacons.

In the episode [Make Tracks](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Make_Tracks), the Decepticons use a radio signal to control humans and Autobots alike.

Comment: Beast Machines: They weren't reformatted, they had a *shell program* running.